# Hide Overflow on a Specific WordPress Template

Tags: css, page-template

I'm trying to hide the overflow in CSS for specific template pages but can't seem to get it to work - I know that template pages are prefixed with a class but this doesn't seem to help targeting.

I think I could use the is_page_template() function to hide the overflow with JS but this should be simpler with CSS.

So this works...

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

but this doesn't work...

```
html .page-template-showreel-php {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Any ideas why? Surely this should be possible with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
html .page-template-showreel-php {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

...will target `body.page-template-showreel-php`. So, two questions:

1. Do you have the `<?php body_class(); ?>` template tag inside of the `<body>` HTML tag?
2. Is hiding overflow on the `<body>` tag *really* what you're after, or do you need to target a descendant element?

**EDIT**

There is no semantic or programmatic reason that you can't re-use the `<?php body_class(); ?>` template tag inside the `<html>` tag also. So, you might consider:

`<html <?php body_class(); ?>>`

and then:

```
html.page-template-showreel-php {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Worth a shot...

Comment: Hi Chip..

1. Yes
2. What I am trying to achieve is hide the vertical scrollbar completely on the page. Normally I would just use html {overflow:hidden;} but in this case I only want to target a template page.

Here is a link to help conceptualise what I'm trying to do...
www.jaygeorge.co.uk/gwennan-sage/showreels
The vertical scrollbar should be hidden because it's distracting and I would like the page to be button driven considering my target audience (non-web-savvy people who prefer clicking buttons over scrolling)

Comment: See answer update...

Comment: Hi Chip,

That works great, thanks a lot. If you refresh http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/gwennan-sage/showreels/ you can see your code working.

Cheers, Jay